# Actionmailer for Appove Account - Email Not Send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I'm trying to create an email which is sent when admin click to active account for user

user has_one :account and account belongs_to :user

in user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :Trackable, :rememberable, :recoverable
attr_accessible :account, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_attributes, :approved

has_one :account

end
```

in account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :address, :approved, :name
  belongs_to :user

end
```

in accounts_controller.rb

```
def activate
  @accounts = Account.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.where(:id => @accounts.id)
  if (@accounts.update_attributes(approved: true)) && (@users.update_all(approved: true))
   AccountMailer.activate_account(@users).deliver   
   redirect_to accounts_path
  else
   redirect_to accounts_path
  end 
end
```

in account_mailer.rb

```
class AccountMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "kapanjadi@gmail.com"

  def activate_account(user)
    @users = user   
        @account = account.find_by_user_id(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Activation Account", :from => "kapanjadi@gmail.com")
  end
end
```

in account_mailer/activate_account.text.erb

```
congratulation, your account is active now
```

setup_mailer.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "localhost:3000",
  :user_name            => "kapanjadi@gmail.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

but an email not send to email user, and no error..
these did not happened to any other action.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

in accounts_controller.rb

```
def activate
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.where(:id => @account.id)
  if (@account.update_attributes(approved: true)) && (@user.update_all(approved: true))
   AccountMailer.activate_account(@user,@account).deliver   
   redirect_to accounts_path
  else
   redirect_to accounts_path
  end 
end
```

in account_mailer.rb

```
class AccountMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default :from => "fauzieuy@gmail.com"

  def activate_account(user,account)
    @account = account
    @accounts = Account.find_by_user_id(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Activation", :from => "kapanjadi@gmail.com")
  end

end
```

error

```
undefined method `email' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3e7c720>
```

Comment: I've had this problem before, Gmail disregards the email. Nothing you can do about it. I suggest using an alternative SMTP server such as sendgrid.com

Comment: no, these did not happened to any other action, smtp gmail is working for other action.
I think there is a mistake on controller or mailer, but I do not know the location of the error.

Comment: @users is a list in accounts_controller.rb, not just a single row. Use "find" rather then "where"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in accounts_controller.rb

```
def activate
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.where(:id => @account.id)
  if (@account.update_attributes(approved: true)) && (@user.update_all(approved: true))


    user_account = account.find_by_user_id(@user)
    AccountMailer.activate_account(@user,user_account,@account.user.mail).deliver 
    redirect_to accounts_path
  else
    redirect_to accounts_path
  end 
end
```

in account_mailer.rb

```
class AccountMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "kapanjadi@gmail.com"

  def activate_account(user,account,to)
    @users = user   
    @account = account
    mail(:to => to, :subject => "Activation Account",  :from=>"kapanjadi@gmail.com")
  end
end
```

The above will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why is everything plural *(`@accounts` and `@users`)*?

```
def activate
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])

  redirect_to accounts_path and return if @account.nil? # handles bad `params[:id]`

  if @account.update_attributes(approved: true) && @account.user.update_attributes(approved: true)
   AccountMailer.activate_account(@account.user).deliver   
   redirect_to accounts_path and return
  end 

  redirect_to accounts_path
end
```

Comment: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I'm just going off of what you've provided; you said an `Account` `belongs_to` a `User`, so `@account.user` should be a valid relationship as long as the `@account` assignment is valid (ie. you're providing a valid `:id` through `params[:id]` for an `Account` that has an associated `User`). You can expect `@account` to be `nil` when a bad `:id` is provided.

Comment: I added a condition for when `@account` is `nil`

Comment: I do not understand why happened, but account belongs_to user , account have user_id column

Comment: Maybe you should show your models and their associations in your Question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20908/discussion-between-deefour-and-kapanjadi-momod)